# SQL Server row versioning overhead on INSERT/SELECT workflow

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, select, insert

SQL Server 2016

Workflow consists of several continuous inserts from one writer and occasional select from a separate reader which returns several rows (all same table). Insert latency is prioritized over select performance. There are no updates/deletes and the selects will never need to return rows that have recently been inserted.

Both ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION and READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT are set to ON.

The issue is that whenever a select query is sent via SqlCommand.ExecuteReader, there is a significant spike in insert latency until SqlCommand.ExecuteReader returns with a SqlDataReader. Since insert latency is important, this degradation needs to be minimized. Select is under read committed isolation level.

Using NOLOCK table hint in the select query does not show this same spike in insert latency & given the use case of the table, dirty reads aren't a concern since they can't happen.

Using READPAST table hint gives similar results to no hint (read committed snapshot).

I haven't found anything online that explains this discrepancy. What overhead is there with read committed snapshot (current state) that impacts insert latency that is not seen when NOLOCK is used?

Comment: What isolation level are your select queries running under? For example, if you're running under SERIALIZABLE, neither snapshot setting will matter. Separately, not all SELECT queries are created equal. How much data are the queries asking for and how are they finding it (i.e. what are the resources consumed and what is the execution plan)? Troubleshoot this like any other long-running query - what are the inserts waiting on and what is causing that wait type?

Comment: The `READPAST` hint has no effect with a SELECT query running in the READ_COMMITTED isolation level in a database with `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON` since row locks are not acquired.